# Unable to change iso properties

Tags: mount, iso, file-properties

Whenever i mount an iso file and wants to change the properties of some files in the iso, (i.e. make a file executable) i always fail to do so. Nautilus wouldn't work, as soon as u click on the make executable option, the tick disappears instantly, this doesn't work in terminal as well (i've tried chmod +x) Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .iso file is readonly by design. If you want to change something in it, first extract it somewhere in your home folder, change files, than create new .iso using Brasero, mkisofs or another program.

However if you want temporarily execute some file, mount .iso using `exec` option like:

```
mount /tmp/disk.iso /mnt rw,exec
```

For additional information refer to

```
man mount
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to at least mount it as rw (read/writable).